# Highcharts table style in tooltips not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My Highchart works fine, but something went wrong with the tooltips.
I want table styled tooltips, and I found an official sample which matches. After lots of trying it is just not working properly.
Please check my js and also have a look my jsfiddle.

This my Highchart:
https://jsfiddle.net/bardirian/5qndmvLh/2

```
    tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3><b>{series.name}　　</b></h3></th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>FS:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>　AT:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    valueDecimals: 2
  }
```

This is the official demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/footerformat/

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @brk as you can see my tooltips table is not working as the official demo, I checked my output html in chrome, they don't even have a <table></table> html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the tooltip options you can set individually for each series:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.tooltip,

but for example `useHTML` is only available to set in main tooltip configuration object:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip

So, you can enable `useHTML` in this way:

```
plotOptions: {
        ...,
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3><b>{series.name}　　</b></h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>FS:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>　AT:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true
},
```

or move all options to the main configuration object:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3><b>{series.name}　　</b></h3></th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>FS:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>　AT:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    valueDecimals: 2
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ev4pnuat/

Comment: Don't know why after I check you Fiddle, I added another 
  tooltip: {
      useHTML: true
  },
after the tooltip..
and it works like yours. Yes, that is what I found from you Fiddle...............

Answer (score 1):

So instead of adding the tooltip inside `plotOptions` just move the `tooltip` to the main object. And remove it from `plotOptions`.

Comment: Could you please give me a jsfiddle demo?